# ¿Cómo crear un vector que contenga 10 números enteros y luego hacer otro vector con los números impares del primer vector?

Tags: c++, array, números-enteros, números-primos

Pude llenar un primer array con los números enteros y mostrarlo, pero no logro hacer un segundo array con los números impares que se encuentran en el primer array.

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
```

Función para cargar el primer array:

```
void cargar(int vec[10]){

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese un numero entero: "<<endl;
        cin>>vec[i];
    }


};
```

Función para mostrar el primer array:

```
void mostrar(int vec[10]){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=10; i++){
        cout<<vec[i];
    }
}
```

Main del programa y llamado a las funciones y variables declaradas:

```
int main(){
    int i, cont =0;
    int vec[10];
    int vec2[10];
    cargar(vec);
   mostrar(vec);
}
```

Buscar números impares en el primer vector:

```
if(vec[i]%2 != 0){
    cont++;
}
int const tam = cont;
for (i = 0; i<tam; i++){
    if (vec[i]%2 !=0){
        vec2[cont] = vec[i];
        cont++;
    }
}

for (i=0; i<tam; i++){
    cout<<vec2[i];
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, la más acorde con los estilos de programación actuales sería:

```
int main(){
    int i, cont =0;
    int vec[10];
    int vec2[10];

    cargar(vec);
    mostrar(vec);

    std::copy_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec),
                 std::begin(vec2),
                 [](int v) { return (v & 1) == 1; });

    return 0;
}
```

La función [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) de la cabecera `<algorithm>` copia los elementos de una colección a otra cuando éstos cumplan una condición.

La condición a cumplir se comprueba con una función lambda, que en este caso comprueba que el último dígito binario de el número sea `1`, característica que comparten todos los números impares.

Pero usar esa función en tu código se ve extraño, ya que el resto del código no sigue las premisas de los estilos contemporáneos de programación, mi consejo es que cambies las formaciones<sup>1</sup> por contenedores, y los `for` tradicionales por su versión de rango:

```
// El contenedor se pasa por REFERENCIA para ser modificado dentro.
void cargar(std::array<int, 10> &datos) {
    int i = 0; 
    // No se necesitan variables de control, el bucle ya conoce el tamaño.
    for (auto &dato : datos) {
    //        ^ <--- El dato es referencia, para poder modificarlo.
        std::cout << "Ingrese un numero entero " << ++i << ":\n";
        std::cin >> dato;
    }
}

// El contenedor se pasa por REFERENCIA CONSTANTE ya que no pretende ser modificado.
void mostrar(const std::array<int, 10> &datos) {
    for (const auto &dato : datos) {
    //   ^^^^^      ^ <--- El dato es referencia constante, no lo modificamos.
        std::cout << dato << '\n';
    }
}

int main(){
    // Añadimos las llaves para indicar que queremos que estén vacíos (inicializado a cero).
    std::array<int, 10> vec{}, vec2{};

    cargar(vec);
    mostrar(vec);

    std::copy_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec),
                 std::begin(vec2),
                 [](int v) { return (v & 1) == 1; });

    std::cout << "Impares: ";
    mostrar(vec2);

    // Es aconsejable que 'main' devuelva un valor, tal y como indica su firma.
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLbboMwDH3PV1hMakG0ErA7t/d9wzpNWUhZpJKgEJCqil8fS0hX1o1Kmx9ixT7H9nFC6npdEjIMV4yTXVtQSJlolKS4ytEUw1Li/VlgVwrJ1LtGIdDWCVYAwbLE0m1UEccjI2VcrSAMclgUWInGg8OINqZTwCCDIIFTbCskuLhVwuIhhl80Y2MDIloFaQrOEy8lbSi0HHhbUSmAcmWcY9K@z0ZUvOFOMlOFccjzsc2U7ZE9J2WV2YmWRgRvFPxN4CjGEv4paQRqv9zw5YWpzPYqzLjrTXXmxuooOfQr46JDn6AT9vhUOu5NHb5U2ij6MVu9f2Vb@7hvtNStDWxls5QX9nom6lzdiRRdgj2/uEZXp5cDkqpWcnA7WEDoQZZBmEA/M9bXL6hqrL9BDM6snug781g7sMh@GEIUoWt0g27RHbpHD@gRhQH6INsdLpthrRtlxPcj/Ak)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *array*.

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void cargar(int vec[10]) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {// no usa '<=' aqui, solo '<' porque los índices de 0 a 9, no 10
        cout << "Ingrese un numero entero " << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
        cin >> vec[i];
    }
}

void mostrar(int vec[10]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {// no usa '<=' aqui, solo '<' porque los índices de 0 a 9, no 10
        cout << vec[i];
    }
}

int main() {

    int i=0, cont = 0;// asigna cero a 'i'
    int vec[10];
    int vec2[10];
    cargar(vec);
    mostrar(vec);

    int i2 = 0; // usa 'i2' calcular los numeros impares
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (vec[i] % 2 != 0) {
            vec2[i2] = vec[i];
            i2++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < i2; i++) {
        cout << vec2[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```